# Perform backup of a file with selectable number of backups

Tags: python

So I am making a program, the program keeps its previous running state in a file. Sometimes things happen and I have to revert to a "last known good" state. This means that the file needs to be backed up prior to being used.

So I wrote this little function to do the backup, and I'd love to hear your opinions/suggestions:

```py
import shutil
from pathlib import Path


def make_backup(the_file: Path, levels: int = 2):
    if not the_file.exists():
        return
    suff = the_file.suffix
    # prev0 is temporary; the loop will rename it to prev1
    shutil.copy(the_file, the_file.with_suffix(".prev0" + suff))
    for n in range(levels, 0, -1):
        prev_n = the_file.with_suffix(f".prev{n}{suff}")
        prev_b = the_file.with_suffix(f".prev{n-1}{suff}")
        if prev_b.exists():
            prev_n.unlink(missing_ok=True)
            prev_b.rename(prev_n)
```

So let's say the file is `state.dat`, upon first run you'll have `state.prev1.dat`, the next run you'll have `state.prev1.dat` and `state.prev2.dat`, and so on depending on what you set `levels` to.

I'm open to suggestions & critiques on making this better. Also, feel free to use this in your project if you think you need this :)

Comment: Perhaps use `Path.replace(target)` instead of `.unlink()` and '`.rename()`.  Also, the code for [`logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/logging/handlers.py) is similar.

Comment: @RootTwo wow thanks! I never knew about `Path.replace(target)` before!

Comment: Also the code for `logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler` is a bit complicated and hard to follow. IMHO my code is easier to read + leverages `pathlib.Path` methods better ;-)

Comment: @RootTwo can you put in your suggestion of using `Path.replace()` in an answer so I can upvote and checkmark it? Thanks!